# How to redirect requests to my domain to an index in a subfolder while keeping the domain URL and using .htaccess?

Tags: php, reactjs, .htaccess

I am using React with a PHP index in a subfolder `/php/index.php` to be able to rewrite meta tags before rendering the `index.html` (which renders the app with react).

How to have requests to my website pass by `/php/index.php` every time while keeping the URL which match with my react app?
For example, if I type `https://example.com/mypage`, I want to keep this exact URL in the address bar while passing by `index.php` to render the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Jacques Giraudel!

You can route requests to any of your .php file by .htaccess
In your case it can look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f - take all requests which is not direct to any file
RewriteRule . php/index.php [L,QSA] - and route to php/index.php
```

Best regards

Comment: This won't rewrite requests to the root if that is required. If you did want to do that, probably easiest to just change the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ from `.` (something) to `^` (anything). (The `QSA` flag is not required here. And be careful of those line-end "comments" - these should be made into proper full-line `# comments` to be valid.)